# All open Browsers crashing after workstation is unlocked

Tags: browser

All the open browsers terminate (IE11 / Chrome / Firefox, either or all in any combination) if workstation is locked and unlocked

Comment: So? What exactly do you want? Is this a programming question?

Comment: General system usage problem. please help to identify the possible causes which could lead to browsers closing automatically.